# How to generate a report in Arcmap 10.2 which counts the number of entries in an attribute table of a certain value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, reports

I am generating an attribute table which may have many thousands of entries. There is a column (one of perhaps 20 or so) for 'vegetation type'. I need to generate a report (or some other easily exportable format) which automatically counts and lists how many times each vegetation type is included in the table. There's far too many entries to do manually and I will need to run the process a number of times so I'm hoping there's a way to automate the process.

For example the attribute table may look like
FID  COLOR
0     Red
1     Blue
2     Green
3     blue
4     blue
5     green
6     blue
7     green
8     red
9     blue
10    yellow

The report would then say something like
Blue: 5
Red: 2
Green: 3
Yellow: 1
Total: 11

Comment: I guess there is some statistic tool that can do this, but it also wouldn't be overly complicated to write python script with a search cursor that calculates the number of entries for each type. Is that an option for you, unless someone knows of an existing tool?

Comment: Hi martin thanks for the idea. I'm not opposed to using  python script to do this but I've never done one before and aren't too sure how they are implemented into arcgis?

Answer (score 1):

You could always summarize the table. To do this select the column you want and right click on it and select the summarize option. If I understand your question correctly this is what you want right?

You can find more information on arcgis help:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/summarizing-data-in-a-table.htm

Comment: Will this provide me with the number of entries for each value?

Comment: yes, it should give you a new table, containing the number of entries for each value